# Issue Importing Grafana Dashboard with ID 16604 for Azure API Management Monitoring

Tags: grafana, azure-api-management

I am trying to create a dashboard in Grafana to monitor HTTP status codes for my Azure API Management Service. I am looking to import a pre-built dashboard with the ID 16604. I have confirmed that the diagnostic settings are enabled on my APIM service and have been set up to send logs and metrics to my Log Analytics workspace.

when attempting to import the dashboard into Grafana, I encounter an issue where the import process fails. I am not receiving a specific error message in Grafana that points to the cause of the failure.